# Setting the Height of Matplotlib Histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with changing the height of the bars of a histogram.

I have the following histogram:

```
x = [1,2,
     11,12,
     21,22,
     31,32,33,34,35,
     41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,
     51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
     61,62,63,64,65,66,
     71,72,73,74,75,67,
     81,82,83,
     91,92,
     101]
num_bins = [0,3,10,30,40,50,65,80,90,100]  

n, x,_ = plt.hist(x, num_bins)
plt.show()
```

[image: Random Histogram]

With the same data, i want to create a histogram with the same bin width, but the height for each bar should be changed to the total height of the bar divided by its bin width.

So for example, the total hight of the first bar is 2, its bin width is 3. Therefore new bin should have height 2/3, with width still 3, and so on.

Thank you so much!

Comment: The height of a histogram bar is the count of values in that bin. If you want a different shaped plot, you would need a `bar` instead of a `hist`

Comment: You have the counts stored in `n` and can calculate the width of each bin from `x`. I bet you are able to create your bar graph with these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you are looking for a normalized histogram. This could be achieved via the `density` argument. However it will be normalized to `1`. Instead you are looking for a normalization to the total number of data. So you may multiply the normalized histogram by the length of the array `x`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,
     11,12,
     21,22,
     31,32,33,34,35,
     41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,
     51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
     61,62,63,64,65,66,
     71,72,73,74,75,67,
     81,82,83,
     91,92,
     101]
num_bins = [0,3,10,30,40,50,65,80,90,100]  

n, bins  = np.histogram(x, num_bins, density=True)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], n*len(x), align="edge", width=np.diff(bins), ec="k")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`plt.hist` returns a list of rectangle objects (which you named using the variable `_`). You can modify the height of these objects:

```
# Create your histogram:
n, bins, rects = plt.hist(x, num_bins, ec='k')

# iterate through rectangles, change the height of each
for r in rects:
    r.set_height(r.get_height()/r.get_width())

# set the y limit
plt.ylim(0,1)

plt.show()
```

[image]