# Many plots on one graph (horizontal and vertical) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Hey this is the plot which I want to create
[image]

And here are the details: on `x` axis I want to have the numbers from `0` to `10`, on `y` axis I want to have values from `0` do `60`. For each `i` from interval `[0, 10]`, I have `10000` numbers. Black line is the mean of all the numbers for each `i`. For selected `i`s (`i=2` and `i=6` on the graph) I want to plot histogram vertically. What is important I want to use `density=True` in `hist` function. The most difficult part is to fix the height of all the histograms to `3` in terms of `x` axis values (red one starts at 2 and the highest point is at 5 and the blue one starts at 6 and ends at 9 so the height is 3). Is anyone able to help me? Below is my current code and the plot which is produced - unfortunately the height is much too small.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(11)
res = np.random.randint(0, 60, size = (11, 10000))

means = [res[i, :].mean() for i in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 6), dpi = 300)

ax.plot(x, means)
ax.hist(res[2,:], bins = 100, density = True, orientation = 'horizontal', bottom = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Look into a [violin plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot.html). It sounds like it'd work for your case without having to brute force multiple histograms on one histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a stab at it - [ax.hist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) returns `n`,`bins`, and `patches`. We can modify the `patches` object (aka the rectangles) to set a height (i.e. width in this case because the orientation is horizontal) following the methods suggested in [Setting the Height of Matplotlib Histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528460/setting-the-height-of-matplotlib-histogram).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = range(11)
    res = np.random.randint(0, 60, size=(11, 10000))

    means = [res[i, :].mean() for i in x]

    # Start of figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

    # Red histogram
    n_red, bins_red, rects_red = ax.hist(res[2,:], bins=100, density=True, bottom=2, orientation="horizontal",
                                         rwidth=0.7, color='r', label='Hist i=2')

    scalar_height = 3
    # The values are less than 1, we can just take the value and add 3 to artificially increase the height to 3
    for r_red in rects_red:
        r_red.set_width(r_red.get_width() + scalar_height)

    # Blue histogram
    n_blue, bins_blue, rects_blue = ax.hist(res[6,:], bins=100, density=True, bottom=6, orientation="horizontal",
                                            rwidth=0.7, color='b', label='Hist i=6')

    for r_blue in rects_blue:
        r_blue.set_width(r_blue.get_width() + scalar_height)

    ax.plot(x, means, 'k', label='Average per i')

    ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 60])
    ax.set_xlabel("i")
    ax.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image: Example histogram with new width]